# gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull often report empty message list

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

Why does "gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull" often report an empty message list while there are messages to be acknowleged in the subscription?

See below the effect. The message 118870127432164 is available in the subscription, it wasn't ever acknowleged, yet it is often not reported.

```
lab@ubu1:~$ while :; do date; gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull projects/PROJECT/subscriptions/killbill-queue; done
Wed Jun 13 15:31:48 -03 2018
┌──────┬─────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ DATA │    MESSAGE_ID   │               ATTRIBUTES              │                                                                                 ACK_ID                                                                                 │
├──────┼─────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 6��  │ 118870127432164 │ billingAccountId=000000-000000-000000 │ TDgBRElTK0MLKlgRTgQhIT4wPkVTRFAGFixdRkhRNxkIaFEOT14jPzUgKEUSAgVPAihdeTBLNkFddgA-DRlyfWF0bFlFUAEQB3ZfWBEMYlxORAdzMhhzdWlyalsRBgZGUX9ZXzOA6NOyt7d6ZiQ9XhJLLD5-MzRFQV5AEg │
└──────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Wed Jun 13 15:31:50 -03 2018
Listed 0 items.
Wed Jun 13 15:31:53 -03 2018
Listed 0 items.
Wed Jun 13 15:31:56 -03 2018
Listed 0 items.
Wed Jun 13 15:31:59 -03 2018
┌──────┬─────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ DATA │    MESSAGE_ID   │               ATTRIBUTES              │                                                                                 ACK_ID                                                                                 │
├──────┼─────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 6��  │ 118870127432164 │ billingAccountId=000000-000000-000000 │ TDgBRElTK0MLKlgRTgQhIT4wPkVTRFAGFixdRkhRNxkIaFEOT14jPzUgKEUSAgVPAihdeTBLNkFddgA-DRlyfWF0bFlFUAEQB3ZfWBEMYlxORAdzMhhzdWlyalsRBgZGUX9ZXzOA6NOyt7d6ZiQ9XhJLLD5-MzRFQV5AEg │
└──────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Wed Jun 13 15:32:01 -03 2018
Listed 0 items.
Wed Jun 13 15:32:05 -03 2018
Listed 0 items.
Wed Jun 13 15:32:07 -03 2018
Listed 0 items.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pulled message you are referencing is "outstanding." This means it should not be given to another subscriber until Google Cloud Pub/Sub believes it will fail to get an acknowledgement from the original subscriber. Specifically, it will wait up until the "Acknowledgement Deadline" before it provides another subscriber with the published message.

[From Google's Pub/Sub Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber) (emphasis mine):

> Once a message is sent to a subscriber, the subscriber must either acknowledge or drop the message. A message is considered outstanding once it has been sent out for delivery and before a subscriber acknowledges it. Cloud Pub/Sub will repeatedly attempt to deliver any message that has not been acknowledged or that is not outstanding. **A subscriber has a configurable, limited amount of time, or `ackDeadline`, to acknowledge the message.** Once the deadline has passed, an outstanding message becomes unacknowledged.

From the context you've shared, it looks like you're seeing the default acknowledge deadline timing out:

> An acknowledgment deadline: If your code doesn't acknowledge the message before the deadline, the message is sent again. **The default is 10 seconds.** The maximum custom deadline you can specify is 600 seconds (10 minutes).

Comment: To be clear: this does not mean that exactly one subscriber will receive the message once. Google's documentation is very clear that while they attempt to only send it once, this is not guaranteed. It is very possible that ~1/1000 times you run the test as you did above, you'll still get the message again even if it has already been sent to another subscriber within the acknowledgement deadline window.

Answer (score 0):

The "often pull empty message" title was a bit misleading and implicit, title could also be "**gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull acknowledges**"

Because that's what you'd think has happened with it returns an empty list, from there the answer here would then explain that it did not in fact acknowledge, but the message is just temporarily in 'outstanding' status before the ack deadline is reached, which then it goes back to que again.